# How to make linq to entities or dbcontext use output in an insert statement?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

Output is defined [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) 
Can I utilize output or am I forced to enter the data into two different tables using linq to entities or dbcontext?

Comment: Can you provide a specific situation in which you would want to use `output`?

Comment: If you want every insert into table X to be accompanied by an insert into table Y, you might consider a trigger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not supported by EF. If you want to use `OUTPUT` clause you must execute SQL directly at your own or through ADO.NET directly or trhough `Database.ExecuteSqlCommand`.